# Exportings pages from InDesign using section tag in HTML5

Tags: html, adobe-indesign

Is it possible to export pages tagged using `<section>` from InDesign CC?

Using the Articles workflow or Paragraph Styles don't seem to allow for the flexibility to specify the tag for export at the page level.

There seems to only be the ability to control classes and select from a limited number of predefined HTML tags at the paragraph level.

I saw a somewhat [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061077/convert-indesign-ouput-to-html5), but it's almost two years old so I'm hoping this is possible now.

Ultimately looking for easiest way to go from InDesign to Reveal.js

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to find a way to setup `section` tags that's fairly simple in InDesign.

1. Go to **Object Styles** and select the style. If you're not using any styles in the document just double click on **Basic Text Frame**
2. Under **Basic Attributes** go down to **Export Tagging.**
3. In the **Tag** field you can specify any tag, so just type `section`.

When you export to HTML you'll see all the content within that text frame is inside a `section` tag.

The same idea works with **Paragraph Styles**, but it's somewhat confusing as InDesign list a handful of tags, but what's not intuitive is that you can simply type in any HTML tag you want.